# Start a Docker container at startup in Linux on Azure

Tags: linux, azure, docker

I have a Linux Virtual Machine on Azure. On this machine I installed Docker. At the startup, I want to run a Docker container. For that, I created a `startup_script.sh` in the `tmp` folder with this content

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e USER=rstudio 
     -e PASSWORD=mypassword myacr.azurecr.io/mycontainer
```

then I run this command

```
chmod u+x /tmp/startup_script.sh
```

Then, under `etc/systemd/system` I created a service

```
[Unit]
Description=Run script at startup after network becomes reachable
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/tmp/startup_script.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then, run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable run-at-startup.service
```

When I restart the machine, the Docker container is not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker recommends that you use its restart policies, and avoid using process managers like systemctl to start containers (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/).

First, you need to make sure that Docker Daemon (i.e. Docker service) start on boot.
On Debian and Ubuntu, the Docker service is configured to start on boot by default. To automatically start Docker and Containerd on boot for other distros, use the commands below:

```sh
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl enable containerd.service
```

If you're on Windows, make sure that you ticked `Start Docker Desktop when you log in` in Docker Desktop settings.

Then, for each container you want to start on boot, you need to use the `--restart` flag when running the container, e.g.:

```sh
sudo docker run --restart always -d -p 8787:8787 -e USER=rstudio 
      -e PASSWORD=mypassword myacr.azurecr.io/mycontainer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the Docker container after starting the virtual machine without the user logging in, your `.service` file should be like this:

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=My Docker container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start my_container_name
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop my_container_name

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This file, for example named `mycontainer.service`, should be placed in the `/etc/systemd/system/`.
You need to pull the image and run it with your preferred parameters for your container to be created.
And you have to enable your new service, as well as `docker.service` and `containerd.service`:

```bsh
sudo systemctl enable mycontainer.service
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl enable containerd.service
```